# Twitter Bootstrap modal is not working in IE7

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

```
<div class="modal hide" id="modalId">
  <div class="modal-header" style="padding:30px 10px">
    <h3 style="float:left">Some text here</h3>
    <input type="image" src="image_path" alt="loading..." class="pull-right" />
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body" style="clear:both">
    <!-- I have a table here-->   
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
     <!-- I have a button here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

code for the modal which will be called on button click

```
$('#modalId').modal({
    backdrop: 'static',
    keyboard: false,
    show: true
});
```

Here The problem I am facing is, in fornt of modal pop up a black window is coming.

This works perfectly in firefox, IE 8 but not in IE7.

I tried a lot but could not find the problem here. :(
Can some one please have a look into it. thubjsdaps14

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have commented the following line in bootstrap.js

`appendTo(document.body)`

and added

`.insertAfter(this.$element)`

For more details refer to https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/3217

Now it is working properly in IE7.

Comment: This most certainly works for IE7, and it also doesn't break the modal in modern browsers. Thanks!

Comment: Although, I did just realize that when doing it this way, the user can click anywhere in the grey area once to bypass the modal window (rather than being forced to click 'okay' or 'x'. Is there a way to fix that while still using this?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest getting the basic modal to work first, you have some CSS in your that may be causing issues (the `clear: both` stands out).

Try this and see if it works:

```
<div class="modal" id="modalId">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h3>Test header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body" style="clear:both">
    Test body 
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
     Test footer
  </div>
</div>

$('#modalId').modal();
```

Comment: Yes that works with "clear: both".. When I removed the class 'hide' from <div class="modal hide" id="modalId"> it worked, but the thing is I want to show this popup only when some one clicks on the button otherwise it should be hidden.

Comment: Oh, then use `$('#modalId').modal('show');` on a click event.

Comment: Thanks Terry for your time. but this I am already doing it here $('#modalId').modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false, show: true }); The modal pop up should initially be hidden from the user. It should popup only on a event i.e., button click.

Comment: Take that `show` out of the constructor.  Use it later in a click event.  `$('#mybutton').click(function() { $('#modalId').modal('show'); });

Comment: Sorry Terry to mis-lead you, 'hide' is not the problem.. It is not working even when I remove hide class. It is something else only not able to figure out.. :(

Comment: I tried the basic modal which u have suggested, even that has the same issue!